# Maximum path sum In a triangle with prime number check

Tags: c#, algorithm, primes

I was given this algorithm task:

You will have a triangle input below and you need to find the maximum sum of the numbers according to given rules below;

1. You will start from the top and move downwards to an adjacent number as in below.
2. You are only allowed to walk downwards and diagonally.
3. You can only walk over NON PRIME NUMBERS.

   ```
        1
       8 4
     2  6  9
    8  5  9  3
   ```

As you can see this has several paths that fits the rule of NOT PRIME NUMBERS; 1>8>6>9, 1>4>6>9, 1>4>9>9
1 + 8 + 6 + 9 = 24.  As you see 1, 8, 6, 9 are all NOT PRIME NUMBERS and walking over these yields the maximum sum.

According to above rules what is the maximum sum of below input? It means please take this pyramid as an input (as file or constants directly inside the code) for your implementation and solve by using it.

```
                                  215
                               193 124
                             117 237 442
                           218 935 347 235
                         320 804 522 417 345
                       229 601 723 835 133 124
                     248 202 277 433 207 263 257
                   359 464 504 528 516 716 871 182
                 461 441 426 656 863 560 380 171 923
               381 348 573 533 447 632 387 176 975 449
             223 711 445 645 245 543 931 532 937 541 444
           330 131 333 928 377 733 017 778 839 168 197 197
        131 171 522 137 217 224 291 413 528 520 227 229 928
      223 626 034 683 839 053 627 310 713 999 629 817 410 121
    924 622 911 233 325 139 721 218 253 223 107 233 230 124 233
```

Note that, each node has only two children here (except the most bottom ones). As an example, you can walk from 215 to 124 (because 193 is a prime) then from 124 to either 237 or 442. From 124 you cannot go to 117 because it’s not a direct child of 124.

I know there are different approaches of solving this problem which can be

- Brute Force method
- Dynamic Programming method

I used Dynamic Programming method approach due to its efficiency:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        //get input
        var input = GetInput();

        string[] arrayOfRowsByNewlines = input.Split('\n');

        var tableHolder = FlattenTheTriangleIntoTable(arrayOfRowsByNewlines);

        var result = WalkThroughTheNode(arrayOfRowsByNewlines, tableHolder);

        Console.WriteLine($"The Maximum Total Sum Of Non-Prime Numbers From Top To Bottom Is:  {result[0,0]}");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static string GetInput()
    {

            const string input = @"   215
                                   193 124
                                  117 237 442
                                218 935 347 235
                              320 804 522 417 345
                            229 601 723 835 133 124
                          248 202 277 433 207 263 257
                        359 464 504 528 516 716 871 182
                      461 441 426 656 863 560 380 171 923
                     381 348 573 533 447 632 387 176 975 449
                   223 711 445 645 245 543 931 532 937 541 444
                 330 131 333 928 377 733 017 778 839 168 197 197
                131 171 522 137 217 224 291 413 528 520 227 229 928
              223 626 034 683 839 053 627 310 713 999 629 817 410 121
            924 622 911 233 325 139 721 218 253 223 107 233 230 124 233";
        return input;
    }

    private static int[,] WalkThroughTheNode(string[] arrayOfRowsByNewlines, int[,] tableHolder)
    {
        // walking through the non-prime node
        for (int i = arrayOfRowsByNewlines.Length - 2; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arrayOfRowsByNewlines.Length; j++)
            {
                //only sum through the non-prime node
                if ((!IsPrime(tableHolder[i, j])))
                {
                    tableHolder[i, j] = Math.Max(tableHolder[i, j] + tableHolder[i + 1, j],
                        tableHolder[i, j] + tableHolder[i + 1, j + 1]);
                }
            }
        }
        return tableHolder;
    }

    private static int[,] FlattenTheTriangleIntoTable(string[] arrayOfRowsByNewlines)
    {
        int[,] tableHolder = new int[arrayOfRowsByNewlines.Length, arrayOfRowsByNewlines.Length + 1];

        for (int row = 0; row < arrayOfRowsByNewlines.Length; row++)
        {
            var eachCharactersInRow = arrayOfRowsByNewlines[row].Trim().Split(' ');

            for (int column = 0; column < eachCharactersInRow.Length; column++)
            {
                int number;
                int.TryParse(eachCharactersInRow[column], out number);
                tableHolder[row, column] = number;
            }
        }
        return tableHolder;
    }

    public static bool IsPrime(int number)
    {
        // Test whether the parameter is a prime number.
        if ((number & 1) == 0)
        {
            if (number == 2)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 3; (i * i) <= number; i += 2)
        {
            if ((number % i) == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return number != 1;
    }




}
```

Can somebody help me go through the code and see if there is a better way of solving it.

Comment: DP is the best way to solve this problem, so this is largely a request to review your code, which is not appropriate for [so]. It might be appropriate for [codereview.se], depending on exactly what type of feedback you're looking for.

Comment: @dukeling Thanks for your comments

Comment: The statement of the problem does not say what to do if there is no valid path. Is the "maximum sum" in that case zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method seems pretty reasonable for this specific problem. This problem is a simplified version of a more general problem; you might consider solving the more general problem.

- Construct a directed graph where the nodes are the elements of the triangle and the directed edges go from a node to the nodes that can be reached.
- Create a start node, with an edge going to the top of the triangle, and a stop node, with edges going from every bottom node to it.
- Remove all edges that go to a node that is a prime number.
- The weight of an edge is the *negative* value of the node it points to; the stop node is of value zero.
- Now you have a weighted directed acyclic graph. Use the standard minimum-path finding algorithm to find the least cost path from start to stop nodes.
- The least cost is the negative of the value you are looking for.

This technique works for any weighted directed acyclic graph, not just ones in the triangle shape.

Answer (score 1):

The prime check is not very efficient, but it doesn't really matter for such small numbers. Your dynamic programming approach is good, but there is an error in the logic for the primes. You only check if the parent node is prime. So if both children are prime the parent node can never be part of a valid path but you still promote the bigger one of the two primes + the parent value if the parent isn't prime. How to fix it:

1. On the lowest level: if a number is prime set it to -1.
2. On the next levels: if the number is prime or both children are < 0 set it to -1 otherwise take the number + the max of the children as before.
3. If the top node has value -1 there is no valid path to the bottom othewise it is the sum of the maximum path *without stepping on primes*.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below solution in Java:

```
// Creating 2 dimensional array with the input triangle
int[][] data = Files.lines(Paths.get("E:\\Personal\\triangle2.txt"))
        .map(s -> stream(s.trim().split("\\s+")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray()).toArray(int[][]::new);

int[][] originalData = Files.lines(Paths.get("E:\\Personal\\triangle2.txt"))
        .map(s -> stream(s.trim().split("\\s+")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray()).toArray(int[][]::new);

/*
 * Below would be code flow if we didnt had to consider skipping the
 * prime numbers.
 * for (int lengthIndex = data.length - 1; lengthIndex >  0; lengthIndex--)
 *   for (int i = 0; i < data[lengthIndex].length - 1;  i++)
 *       data[lengthIndex - 1][i] += Math.max(data[lengthIndex][i],data[lengthIndex][i + 1]);
 */

// Using the bottom-up approach starting from the lowermost node to upwards
for (int lengthIndex = data.length - 1; lengthIndex > 0; lengthIndex--)
    for (int i = 0; i < data[lengthIndex].length - 1; i++) {
        System.out.println("lenghtindex is" + lengthIndex);
        if(!checkPrimeOnOriginalArray(data[lengthIndex - 1][i]) || (lengthIndex == 1)) {
            System.out.println("gettign here");
            data[lengthIndex - 1][i] += Math.max(
                    data[lengthIndex][i],data[lengthIndex][i + 1]);
            System.out.println("-->"+data[lengthIndex - 1][i]);
        }
        else {
            data[lengthIndex - 1][i] = 0;
        }
    }

//data[lengthIndex - 1][i] += Math.max(
//      checkPrimeOnOriginalArray(originalData[lengthIndex][i]) ? 0 : data[lengthIndex][i],
//      checkPrimeOnOriginalArray(originalData[lengthIndex][i + 1]) ? 0 : data[lengthIndex][i + 1]);

System.out.println("Maximum Sum Of Path Is : "+data[0][0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think it is not checking the prime number check in the last row and taking max value ?

the code should be look like below:

```
for (int lenIndex = data.length - 1; lenIndex > 0; lenIndex--) {
        for (int i = 0; i < data[lenIndex].length - 1; i++) {
            System.out.println("---------------------");
            System.out.println("lenIndex is : " + lenIndex);
            if (!isPrimeNum(data[lenIndex - 1][i]) || (lenIndex == 1)) {
                if (lenIndex == data.length - 1) {
                    data[lenIndex - 1][i] += Math.max(isPrimeNum(data[lenIndex][i]) ? 0 : data[lenIndex][i],
                            isPrimeNum(data[lenIndex][i + 1]) ? 0 : data[lenIndex][i + 1]);

                    System.out.println("data[lenIndex][i] : " + data[lenIndex][i]+ " data[lenIndex][i + 1] :"+ data[lenIndex][i + 1]);
                    System.out.println("Number select for Sum #" + Math.max(isPrimeNum(data[lenIndex][i]) ? 0 : data[lenIndex][i],
                            isPrimeNum(data[lenIndex][i + 1]) ? 0 : data[lenIndex][i + 1]));
                } else {
                    data[lenIndex - 1][i] += Math.max(data[lenIndex][i], data[lenIndex][i + 1]);
                    System.out.println("data[lenIndex][i] : " + data[lenIndex][i]+ " data[lenIndex][i + 1] :"+ data[lenIndex][i + 1]);
                    System.out.println("Number select for Sum #" + Math.max(data[lenIndex][i], data[lenIndex][i + 1]));
                }
                System.out.println("Afrer Sum #" + data[lenIndex - 1][i]);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Prime Number - Skiping : " + data[lenIndex - 1][i]);
                data[lenIndex - 1][i] = 0;
            }
        }
```